# Website layout broken if not using Internet Explorer 8 with domain added to compability view

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, layout, internet-explorer-8

I have been searching for a very long time for a solution to my problem but I have yet to find anything that works.

I built a website a few years back when Internet Explorer 8 was the main used browser and added layout to make things look good for it specifically. Nowadays some layout things look like crap on anything other than internet explorer 8 (you also need to add the domain to compatibility view settings). I know that I should most likely rewrite everything but I was wondering if there was no way to identify the specific layout issue or a dirty `css` fix to make it look good using IE8+/Chrome?

One page in Chrome:
http://sv.tinypic.com/r/oh8yoi/9

Same page in Internet Explorer 8:
http://sv.tinypic.com/r/2wnzcz4/9

HTML from that page:

```html
<div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 523px; height: 38px; background-color:#cccccc">
    <span style="width: 190px; height: 38px" class="border1px">
        <div class="INBDheadline">Kund</div>
        <div class="INBDcontent"></div>
    </span>
    <span style="width: 104px; height: 38px; margin-left:-1px;" class="border1px">
        <div class="INBDheadline">Ort</div>
        <div class="INBDcontent"></div>
    </span>
    <span style="width: 81px; height: 38px; margin-left:-1px;" class="border1px">
        <div class="INBDheadline">Avgångstid</div>
        <div class="INBDcontent"></div>
    </span>
    <span style="width: 81px; height: 38px; margin-left:-1px;" class="border1px">
        <div class="INBDheadline">Orderrader</div>
        <div class="INBDcontent"><span id="OrderRowCount">0</span></div>
    </span>
    <span style="width: 71px; height: 38px; margin-left:-1px;" class="border1px">
        <div class="INBDheadline">Kollin</div>
        <div class="INBDcontent"><span id="DFPCount">0</span></div>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS classes:

```css
.INBDheadline {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 8pt;
    text-indent:4px;
}
.INBDcontent {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 8pt;
    text-indent:4px;
}
.border1px {
    border: 1px #000000 solid;
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions (other than the obvious solution to rebuild everything) would be greatly appreciated!

**Progress 1**
Adding the following css for the border1px class seems to prevent the newline on each `<span>` element making it look much better:

```css
.border1px {
    border: 1px #000000 solid;
    float: left;
}
```

**Progress 2**
Adding the following css seems to fix the border causing extra width:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Are there errors in the HTML? Browsers nowadays have different error correction rules than IE8 had. Also, are you using quirks mode?